# How do I open a OneDrive file in Preview using Applescript?

Tags: applescript, ms-office, preview, office-365

How do I open a OneDrive for Business file using Preview using Applescript? I’ve tried this so far:

```
tell application "Preview" to open POSIX file "Users/myname/One Drive - MySchoolOrCompany/path/to/file"
```

However, I get this error message from Preview (`filename` is the name of my file):

> The file “filename” couldn't be opened because there is no such file.

I have checked and the file path is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't have a forward slash before `Users`:

```
tell application "Preview" to open POSIX file "/Users/myname/One Drive - MySchoolOrCompany/path/to/file"
```